# OpenCl keeps throwing CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES

Tags: c++, opencl

I wrote Mandelbulb generation addon for blender, than I moved it to c++ dll and OpenCL: https://github.com/63n0m3/Mandelbulb_object_blender_addon/tree/main

All functionality is written at this stage, but I cannot figure out why I am being thrown CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES error that comes with a gpu driver crash. I have nVidia 466 driver.
The version that is in the main branch can be compiled and executed without compilation to dll if you have OpenCL environment. There are 3 seperate runs in main():

1. running
2. crashes in cleaning
3. crashes in generation

The only difference between those 3 is the resolution of the mandelbulb. Amounts of memory used would be in single megabytes for first 2 cases rather than 11gig available. What do you think? Should I look into values mentioned in [Determine max global work group size based on device memory in OpenCL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23017005/determine-max-global-work-group-size-based-on-device-memory-in-opencl) and spread local group sizes manually?

Comment: Your voxel buffer appears to be sizeof(float)*(resolution **3)*8 so for resolution 100, that's 32MiB. Still, its far short of what's available so I don't think that's your problem. I don't know what is causing the error, but just have some suggestions. If you are only using one m_type, then I suggest you build your OpenCL program with only the kernels you'll need. The other thing I thought of is that driver 466 is quite old and I don't think it is a major release like 470, on linux at least, sorry but I don't know about Windows. Maybe try a different driver?

Comment: Yes 466 is not that late after introduction of OpenCL 3.0 by nVidia. One more weird thing that I just cant handle is why the errors happen on ReadBuffers. So much has happened before on those buffers during previous operations.

Comment: The program keeps executing and still gets return value despite crashed driver.

Comment: Update: I reduced kernels to just 2 at adding program sources stage: generation kernel and Consol_8_to_8. It didnt fix it. I tried making manual small local workgroups: NDRange(200,1,1) for generation kernel, it didnt fix it either. To be fair it does always crash at this 200 case and maybe even those above operations made it crash less often, its hard to pinpoint the location of the issue in such case :( I looked for a new driver and suprisingly could not find the old one of mine on webpage.

Comment: You don't define CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION in your program. If you're using OpenCL 3.0 features you probably should add #define CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 300 to your code. I doubt that will magically make it work for all your test cases though. If Nvidia have removed the driver you're using from their website, it's probably because it is no longer supported. If you're using a 1080ti or 2080ti, then you should be able to use the most up-to-date driver. Sorry, but I don't know what else to suggest.

Comment: Yes ofc, warning message about OCL version with message that it will default to OCL 300. Does it mean that you compiled it and did it run without crashing? I left code without define as it seems to compile also for 2.0 if there was need to use it for an older hardware.

Comment: I didn't get it to compile, but I didn't persevere with it. I have linux and normally only compile c so my development environment isn't really set up for it. I have a really old GPU (Tesla K20X) as well and I wasn't sure it would run opencl  3.0 anyway so I gave up. Maybe I'll try again sometime when I have a spare half hour. I think I have the 470 driver installed.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran all three cases of your program without getting the CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES error message. I got 4x CL_SUCCESS for the first two, and 2x for the third. Is this correct? It appeared to complete normally but the third case finished much faster than the second (9s vs 64s). Anyway, I think the fact that your driver is no longer available for download strongly suggest that it is out of date.

I used Nvidia driver version 470 and a Tesla K20Xm GPU with 6GB RAM and it appeared to work. I had to faff with the headers and add a couple of macros to get it to compile but after that it appeared to be okay. In conclusion, I think your old NVidia driver version is probably the source of your problems.

Comment: Yes it should be 4x CL_SUCCESS and 2x. 2 of them come from the Delete_internal_disconnected_GPU which is not on 200 resolution case. Cleaning phase is more computationally intensive every previously calculated voxel has to iterate through every other voxel there to sum up its surrounding voxels. For blender using this will be necessary because just raw amount of geometric data generated with inside voxels just breaks blender. As for example cant remember what resolution it was(100-200)but it generated 4 500 000 vertices in blender and just raw internal blender generation took for me 50 seconds

Comment: What was the issue with the headers and a macro? Was it something I did wrong? Was it compilation to linux? Was it just OpenCL setup?

Comment: I think the changes I made were just needed because I tried to run it on my linux system and I didn't have cl.hpp installed etc. because I only use c. Let me know if you get it working with a different driver. :)